# Two Subplots in an Animated For-loop Problem

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I am new to Matlab and have some issues regarding making both of my subplots play at the same time. For the first plot, I searched for the peaks and valleys and plot them as the data recognized them as peaks/valleys, and have no problem with it. However, the second plot that I want to show is the displacement gathered from the peaks and valleys and show them when the first plot passes through the peaks/valleys. I also don't know how to incorporate the code for it, and I only know to directly call "plot" on it. My problem is in the for loop I made. Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

```
    % Initialize the plot
    figure(3);
    subplot (2,1,1)
    h = plot(time(1), mag(1)); hold on;   % Start with the first data point
    ylabel('Acceleration');    
    title('Real-time Signal Analysis'); 

    h.XDataSource = 'x1';       % Set the data source properties for dynamic updating
    h.YDataSource = 'y1';


    for i = 1:200:numel (time)
        x1 = time(1:i);
        y1 = mag(1:i);
        refreshdata(h, 'caller');
        drawnow;    

        [pks, locs] = findpeaks (mag,'MinPeakDistance',1500);
        [vks, vlocs] = findpeaks (-mag, 'MinPeakDistance',1300);
        vks = -vks;
    
        valid_vks_indices = vlocs (time(vlocs) <= x1 (end));
        valid_pks_indices = locs (time(locs) <= x1 (end));
    
        if ~isempty (valid_vks_indices)
            plot (time(valid_vks_indices), vks(ismember(vlocs, valid_vks_indices)), 'or');
        end
        if ~isempty (valid_pks_indices)
            plot (time(valid_pks_indices), pks (ismember(locs, valid_pks_indices)), 'or');
        end
        pause(0.001);
    
        subplot (2,1,2);
        xlabel ('Time'); ylabel('Displacement');
     
        for j = i
            vel = cumtrapz (time, mag);
            vel  = filtfilt (b2, a2, vel);
            disp = cumtrapz (time, vel);
            disp = filtfilt (b2, a2, disp); 

            plot (time, disp)
        end
    end
```